# Реально ли обучить нейросеть человеческому вкусу?

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети

Предположим, есть три кучки картинок: отобранные, забракованные и несортированные. Нужно обработать третью. Картинки самой разной тематики и стилистики, отобранные по принципу "понравились, не понравились", иными словами, вкусовщина конкретного человека. Реально ли нейросеть обучить разобрать третью кучку согласно вкуса конкретного человека? И если да, то куда ковырять и насколько глубокие знания для этого нужны?

Comment: Вполне реально! Строите сверточную НС для бинарной классификации картинок. Обучаете ее на большом наборе картинок и вуаля)

Answer (score 2):

Реально. Только у вас это врят-ли получится.

Потому как сначала придется строить соответствующую нейросеть просто для распознавания картинок (учитывая, что ваши знания в этой области примерно равны 0 на это может уйти пол-года а то и  больше).

А потом придется этой сети скормить пару десятков тысяч образцов, которые предварительно разметить на предмет нравится/нет, т.е. отсканировать, предъявить вашему подопытному, получить ответ и корректно ввести и то и другое в компьютер. Вы-то за два-три года может управитесь. А вот подопытный может и сбежать.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне реально. История знает пример реализации такого проекта всего одним человеком. Он обучил нейросеть выбирать в Tinder фото девушек, которые нравятся именно ему. Не могу с ходу найти линк, но вы легко можете загуглить. Если почитаете чуть больше, то сможете прикинуть затраты времени и цену такого проекта.